# java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format VS Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, keystore

I am trying to sign my APK file with keystore.jks file manually to publish my App on Google Play Store.
here are the commands I am following.

```
zipalign -v -p 4 com.VolMobileApp.Android.apk com.VolMobileAppAligned.Android.apk

apksigner sign --ks h2vkeystore.jks --out com.VolMobileAppRelease.Android.apk com.VolMobileAppAligned.Android.apk
```

Here is the issue. I tried to look for a solution but did not succeed.

When Second Command asks

```
Keystore password for signer #1:
```

After filling password it returns the error given below. Earlier there was no error.

```
Failed to load signer "signer #1"
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:666)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:57)
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:71)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
        at com.android.apksigner.SignerParams.loadKeyStoreFromFile(SignerParams.java:353)
        at com.android.apksigner.SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCertsFromKeyStore(SignerParams.java:239)
        at com.android.apksigner.SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCerts(SignerParams.java:181)
        at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.getSignerConfig(ApkSignerTool.java:368)
        at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:291)
        at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:84)
```

I am not able to detect what I am doing wrong, but the difference I notice is in the archived folder structure.

[image]

Comment: have you verified your keystore with the Android `keytool`?

Comment: @Jason Yes, it is verified.

Comment: Do you have special characters in your password, e.g. `!`?  The password has a very narrow range of permissible characters.

Comment: And there is also a similar thread, you can check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217117/apksigner-invalid-keystore-format

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Yes, I do have special characters. The same password I was using earlier was not giving me an error and thank you for the thread.

Comment: Hi  @TheHunterShergill,  have you resolved your problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT No sir, I am still trying to find the solution.

Comment: Have you tried to replace the special characters in your password?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT No did not change the special characters, I think they were not the issue, I resolved it by converting the `.jks` file to the `.keystore` file then and following the same procedure doing `zipalign` and `apksihner`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case solved the problem by signing the .APK whit the values signed into the keystore that we configured to create the APK file in Release mode.

I taked the Microsoft example in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=windows)

[image]

and here I put the same values

[image]

That way a solved my problem with

"java.exe" exited with code 2

But the real information problem was in output:

Failed to load signer "signer #1" java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

At the moment I don't find the real solution to this problem but, this works.